# How to find processes using serial port

Tags: linux, open-files, processes, uclinux

I'm using uclinux and I want to find out which processes are using the serial port. The problem is that I have no `lsof` or `fuser`.

Is there any other way I can get this information?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one-liner should help:

```
ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd/* |grep /dev/ttyS0
```

replace `ttyS0` with actual port name

example output:

```
lrwx------ 1 root dialout 64 Sep 12 10:30 /proc/14683/fd/3 -> /dev/ttyUSB0
```

That means the pid `14683` has the `/dev/ttyUSB0` open as file descriptor `3`

Comment: Running as root, of course :-)

Comment: I did the following : `root:/mnt/app> ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd/* | grep /dev/ttyBF0`. The output I get is `ls: /proc/354/fd/3: No such file or directory`. Forgive my ignorance, but what do I make of that?

Comment: This method is not 100% reliable; though it did not find any processes that have ttyBF0 open, I would check what is pid 354

Comment: @KermittheHermit see the edit, please

Comment: @Serge I've tested this on my laptop with USB to serial adapter. I encounter the same issue even though I'm using /dev/ttyUSB. Do you perhaps have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I did as well: the example in answer I got on laptop I am using to type this message. What distribution do you use, what kernel version?

Comment: That's odd, I've double checked what I'm doing and it's exactly as you say and I know for a fact that I'm using /dev/ttyUSB0. Ubuntu 14.04, kernel version 4.4.0-36.

Comment: yes, indeed strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45264/discussion-between-serge-and-kermit-the-hermit).

Comment: The command in the answer is most probably using process IDs which do not exist anymore by the time the command is actually executed. Remember that shell expansion happens first. An alternative is `\ls -1 /dev/tty* /dev/pts/* | xargs -I{} lsof {}`. Tested on debian.