# Find and kill the process that is using a serial port

Tags: process, kill, ps, serial-port, process-management

I have multiple serial ports to each of which devices are connected. They are listed as `/dev/ttyUSB*`. Now, I need to make sure using a python script that no other process is using any of these before I run a `kermit` script (so that access is not denied) `login_init`. I tried `ps` and `lsof` commands. `lsof` gave the following output:

```
sof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
login_ini 13395       user4    4u   CHR  188,9      0t0  512 /dev/ttyUSB9
python    14410       user4    6u   CHR  188,9      0t0  512 /dev/ttyUSB9
```

I got the `pid`s of the processes alright, but when I give the `killall` command, it says no process found as follows:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~/Scripts$ killall -9 13395
13395: no process found

user4@user-pc-4:~/Scripts$ killall -9 14410
13395: no process found
```

Is this the right and the only way or there are better ways to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`killall` expects a substring of the program's name as argument. To kill a process by its process ID, use `kill`.

You can directly kill all the processes that have a file open with the command `fuser`.

```
fuser -k /dev/ttyUSB9
```

Comment: @TimKennedy I don't recommend the use of `killall` at all — it's the wrong tool for this job anyway. This question is clearly about a Linux system, so warnings about Solaris which most readers of this thread will never use are not useful here.

Comment: This has been working for me, but when run under sudo I'm suddenly having the command lock up hard and I can't even ctrl-C to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the process ID's, you can just use `kill`, i.e.

```
kill -TERM 13395 14410
```

(I would suggest sending a normal `SIGTERM` first, before pushing the `SIGKILL`-button.)

The [`killall` command used in Linux systems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html) kills process by *name*, as does [`pkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html). However, on other systems, such as Solaris, [`killall` kills *everything*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5166/killall-1m.html) (as part of the shutdown procedure), which might be good to keep in mind if you ever use those.

Answer (score 1):

Use below commands to kill pid

`sudo kill -9 13395`

`sudo kill -9 14410`

if you want to kill all(/dev/ttyUSB9) in a single command then use below command

`sudo pkill -9 ttyUSB9`

To list the running process id.then use below command

`ps -ef | grep ttyUSB9`

To list the number of running process id.then, use below commands

`ps -ef | grep ttyUSB9 | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

I solved following serial port related problems in ubuntu 18.04 as follows:

**Problem 1 :  Cannot open /dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied**
Solution  :  Grant permissions to read/write to the serial port with this terminal command --->  `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`
Here replace tty port with your respective ubuntu port.

**Problem 2 : Failed to open /dev/ttyACM0 (port busy)**
Solution  : This problem appears when serial port is busy or already occupied. So kill the busy serial port with command ---> `fuser -k /dev/ttyACM0`. Here replace tty port with your respective ubuntu port.

**Problem 3 : Board at /dev/ttyACM0 is not available**
Solution : In this case your serial port in tools menu will be greyed out. I googled a lot for this, but I none of  solution worked for me. Atlast I tried different arduino board and usb connector and it was working for me. So, if you are having old arduino board (can be solved using required drivers) or defected arduino board then only this problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using `sudo fuser -k` to do this successfully for a long time and it worked fine, but suddenly I'm having the command lock up hard and I can't even ctrl-C to kill it.

Here's my alternative `free_serial` script:

```
# expects serial port string as command line argument
# run with sudo if needed:
# sudo free serial /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_AI06HY2F-if00-port0

TTY_NAME=$(ls -l $0 | grep -o '[^/]*$')
#echo $TTY_NAME

#https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308866/how-to-find-processes-using-serial-port

PID=$(ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/fd/* 2> /dev/null |grep /dev/ | grep $TTY_NAME | grep -o 'proc/.*' | cut -d "/" -f2  2> /dev/null) 

if [ "$PID" ]; then
    echo "killing $PID"
    kill -KILL $PID
    echo done
fi
```